# Generate a random number avoiding duplicates from a given list

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a project and I need to write a function to generate ID's for every client in our the company. There's an existing list of clients already and some of them have a numerical 5 to 6 digits ID ranging from 40,000 to 200,000. There are other existing clients that do not have an ID and I would like to keep consistency with the already existing ID numbers (e.g. 43606 or 125490).

So in order to keep a similar format I created an `Exclusion_List` that contains all of the existing ID numbers. Then I was going to write a function using `np.random.uniform(low=40000, high=200000)` so that generates a number within that range that would look similar to the other ID numbers.

The problem that I have is that I don't know how to set a loop to check if the randomly generated ID is already in the exclusion list and if so; to generate a new one then.

This is what I have so far:

```
exclusions = [43606,125490,...]

def ID_Generator(new_clients): # This is a list of new client

  new_client_IDs = []

  for client in new_clients:

    ID = int(np.random.uniform(low=40000, high=200000))

    while ID not in exclusions:

      new_client_IDs.append(ID)
```

I am not sure how to handle the scenario when the randomly generated number is in the exclusion list. I would love the function to output a dataframe containing the client names in one column and the ID number in a second column.

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Why not use something like this? https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually thought about it but the friction is kind of high if I did that. I say that because these ID numbers I need to share them with different distributors, so if I created a brand new format from scratch, that means that every distributor would need to update their databases and I'm thinking that would be kind of a pain in the back.  Also, the UUID is not that appealing to the eye. This is just what my client wants anyways so that's why.

Comment: What about a simple `if` instead of `while`? `if ID not in exclusions: append() else: pass` or similar? Also, using `set` instead of list can help with speed of lookups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar answer to Niranjan, but no list comprehension needed,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

exlcusion_list = [43606,125490]

free_ids = np.arange(40000, 200000)
free_ids = free_ids[~np.isin(free_ids, exlcusion_list)]

def get_ids(client_names):
    new_client_ids = np.random.choice(free_ids, len(client_names), replace=False)

    return pd.DataFrame(data=new_client_ids, index=client_names, columns=["id"])

print(get_ids(["Bob", "Fred", "Max"]))
```

which gives

```
          id
Bob   125205
Fred  185058
Max    86158
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach I can think as of now is.

1. Generate a list from `40000-200000`.
2. Remove all the `exclusions` from the above list.
3. Randomly pick any id from the remaining list (In case order matters, use ids sequentially).

`import random
 exclusions = [43606,125490]
 all = range(40000,200000)
 remaining = [x for x in all if x not in exclusions]
 random.choice(remaining)`

Answer (score 0):

```
exclusions = [43606,125490,...]
def ID_Generator(new_clients): # This is a list of new client

  new_client_IDs = []

  while len(new_client_IDs) < len(new_clients):
    ID = randint(40000, 200000)
    if ID not in exclusions:
      new_client_IDs.append(ID)
    if list(dict.fromkeys(new_client_IDs)):
      new_client_IDs = list(dict.fromkeys(new_client_IDs))
```